# Why isn't my colorbar appearing in this ImageGrid plot?

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

I've managed to make a set of subplots using `hist2d` and `ImageGrid` with the code below:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

fig = figure(figsize(20, 60))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(1, 3), axes_pad=0.25)
for soa, ax in zip(soalist, grid):
    # grab my data from pandas DataFrame...
    samps = allsubs[allsubs['soa'] == soa]
    x, y = samps['x'], samps['y']

    # calls hist2d and returns the Image returned by hist2d
    img = gazemap(x, y, ax, std=True, mean=True)
    ax.set_title("{0} ms".format(soa * 1000))

# attempt to show a colorbar for that image       
grid.cbar_axes[-1].colorbar(img)

show()  # threw this in for good measure, but doesn't help!
```

I get no explicit error (which is good, because I passed an `Image` to `colorbar`), but my colorbar **does not appear**.  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it!

All I had to do was pass the `cbar_mode` and `cbar_location` kwargs to `ImageGrid`!